# Nonlinear (hyperbola) curve fitting in Java

Tags: java, optimization, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have algorithm that produces data during it's run time. It is guaranteed that the value has downward tend during the time and in ideal conditions it would be something like a hyperbola (or at least it has hyperbolic shape). Basic plotted graph (`x` axis is the time and `y` axis the value) looks like this:

[image: value of algorithm over time]

Now, I would like to predict, how will value look like after `n` time steps during the run time. I tried to use linear or polynomial regression from `org.apache.commons.math3` but obviously, the predictions cannot be good since the curve is not linear nor polynomial. Also both predictions provide curves without downward tend.

To solve this I tried to use [odinsbane's least squares](https://github.com/odinsbane/least-squares-in-java), but I have troubles to provide correct first parameters assumption and therefore I can't fit the curve properly.

So my question is: Is there any kotlin/java library, which could be able to fit my data properly without me providing first parameters estimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution was to use [this](https://github.com/finmath/finmath-lib) and it's `Levenberg–Marquardt` solver. 
I decomposed generic hyperbola function `a + b/(x + c)` into `a * c + a * x + b - y * c = xy` - therefore:

- `setTargetValues` received `x*y` data
- `setValues` provided `a * c + a * x + b - y * c` values
- `setDerivatives` provided `[c + x, 1, a - y]` values

This allowed me to fit "hyperbolic like" data.